# php login in script that only has one user set in a variable

Tags: php, authentication

I'm looking for a php script so my entire site needs a password to access. I don't want a sql database, I just want one user who's credentials are set in a variable.

I have

config.php

```
<?php
$secured = false;
$username = "user";  // Set manually by editing config
$password = "pass";  //Set manually by editing config
?>
```

Then index.html

```
<form action="auth.php" method="post">
Username: <input type='text' name="user" value='' />
Password: <input type='password' name="password" value='' />
<input type='submit' value='Log in' />
</form>
```

Then auth.php (This is what I need coded)

```
<?php
require once "config.php"
If  $secured = false the redirect to page1.html
```

// So if its false don't require authentication at all anywhere on site.

```
If $secured = true then ask for username and password. 
If wrong display error message.
If right redirect to page1.html 
?>
```

That's what I'm trying to achieve. I then also need the login stored as a session variable so it remembers you logged in and checks on each page that you are logged in. Then finally a way to log out. So a button I can just stick somewhere will do the job. Hope this all makes sense.

Question : How does the auth.php script look like?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a "make me a script please" website!

Comment: Then go answer another question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sessions to remember if a user has logged in. To do that, add:

```
session_start();
```

in config.php

On every page that requires log in, add this at the top of the script:

```
require_once('config.php');
if ($secured && (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || !$_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
```

Auth.php should look like the following.

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
If (!$secured) {
    header('Location: page1.html');
    exit;
}
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['user']==$username && $_POST['password']==$password) {
        // OK
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        header('Location: page1.html');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Bad login credentials. <a href=\"index.html\">Try again</a>";
    }
} else {
    // not logging in
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
?>
```

To sign out, just create a script logout.php:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
?>
```

Comment: Okay fixed it. In line 8 there should only be one ) not two after text

Comment: @Michael Extra paranthesis at line 7 fixed. What was the error on line 17?

Comment: @Michael Added sign out script: `To sign out, just create a script logout.php:

    <?php
    require_once('config.php');
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
    ?>`

Comment: The line 17 was knock on from line 7. All fixed now. Thanks. Its redirecting to the login form fine but then it just refreshes the form when you click submit. Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael Ok. Did you include `session_start();` in `config.php`?

Comment: Minor problem there.. The session has already been started somewhere else. On one of the other pages so its gives me an error saying session already started ignore the one on config page.

Comment: @Michael You could try `if (session_id()=='') session_start()` instead.

Comment: I tested it without the other pages in the site. So session_start(); doesn't conflict and its still just refreshing the form

Comment: @Michael Your input name was `user` not `text`. Try `$_POST['user']` instead of `$_POST['text']`. I'm so sorry!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so so much for the help and the after effort! :) :)

Comment: One last question. Does session start have to be in config? Can I put it somewhere else? If so how?

Comment: @Michael You need to call `session_start()` before you access `$_SESSION` and before any output. As long as you follow these two rules, you could put `session_start()` wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session (see [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)) to store if a user is logged in or not.

Once a user is logged in you can set a session that someone is logged in and then on each visit check if session exists and it is valid (using private salt and hash). If session variable does not exist or is invalid direct user to login page.